# What's the difference between distance from CLLocationManager and CMPedometer

Tags: ios, ios9, core-location

I'm writing a running app according to an online tutorial on http://www.raywenderlich.com/97944/make-app-like-runkeeper-swift-part-1. 
In the tutorial,the distance the user has run since the start is calculated from two latest recorded locations using "distanceFromLocation" method in CLLocation. However in CMPedometer there's also a distance data which can be retrieved directly. So which one should I use and why?

Thanks

Comment: Just to note that `CMPedometer` relies on [Apple M7/8/9 chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_motion_coprocessors) (found on iPhone5S and later devices) but is much more efficient since it uses dedicated hardware to collect and process sensor data. Maybe a 'hybrid' solution would be something worth investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMPedometer` relies on the motion tracking chips built into modern iPhones to measure steps and distance travelled by the owner of the device.  It is able to estimate the number of steps taken using motion data, and extrapolate the distance traveled by the user using step counts and estimated stride length.  If a distance estimate is good enough for your purposes, then `CMPedometer` is an easy, power efficient solution to tracking distance travelled.

On the other hand, if you would like the reported distance to be as accurate as possible, you should use `CLLocation` and calculate the distance between each location the user travels through on their workout.  This requires more complex code and an accurate GPS signal.  As an added benefit, you'll be able to use the location data to, for instance, draw a map of where the user ran on their workout.